# C: Undefined reference to LibConfuse internal functions

Tags: c, include

I am testing [LibConfuse](https://github.com/martinh/libconfuse) on **Code::Blocks** trying to build the simplest **first example** on the [tutorial](http://www.nongnu.org/confuse/tutorial-html/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <confuse.h>

int main(void)
{
    cfg_opt_t opts[] =
    {
        CFG_STR("target", "World", CFGF_NONE),
        CFG_END()
    };
    cfg_t *cfg;

    cfg = cfg_init(opts, CFGF_NONE);
    if(cfg_parse(cfg, "hello.conf") == CFG_PARSE_ERROR)
        return 1;

    printf("Hello, %s!\n", cfg_getstr(cfg, "target"));

    cfg_free(cfg);
    return 0;
}
```

But I get the below **errors** when compiling:

```
Undefined reference to "cfg_init".
Undefined reference to "cfg_parse".
Undefined reference to "cfg_getstr".
Undefined reference to "cfg_free".
```

Note that there are no errors about the `#include <confuse.h>` line nor about the constans, like `CFGF_NONE`.

I **installed** LibConfuse with:

```
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get install libconfuse*
```

What is going on here and how can I **solve** it?

**Further Data**:

- **Operating System**: Ubuntu 16.04 .
- Tested on two **different** PC computers.
- Tested on RaspBerry Pi running **RaspBian**.
- **Code::Blocks** version 17.12 .
- Tested compiling on **Clang** with same results.

Another detail: I use to **cross-compile** to FreeBSD target, so I tested this basic program with my usual procedure to generate binaries for **FreeBSD x64**:

```
$ clang -target x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0 --sysroot=/opt/cross-freebsd-10/ main.c
/tmp/main-0044e3.o: En la función `main':
main.c:(.text+0x96): referencia a `cfg_init' sin definir
main.c:(.text+0xb3): referencia a `cfg_parse' sin definir
main.c:(.text+0xde): referencia a `cfg_getstr' sin definir
main.c:(.text+0x104): referencia a `cfg_free' sin definir
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As can be seen, results are the same.

More **details about compilation** (to x64 Linux) when using `clang` :

```
$ clang main.c -v   clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name main.c -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.0 -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdebug-compilation-dir /media/Almacen01/Temporal/CPlusPlus/PruebaGeneral -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 83 -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /tmp/main-06952f.o -x c main.c
clang -cc1 version 3.8.0 based upon LLVM 3.8.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtbegin.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../.. -L/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/main-06952f.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/main-06952f.o: En la función `main':
main.c:(.text+0x96): referencia a `cfg_init' sin definir
main.c:(.text+0xb3): referencia a `cfg_parse' sin definir
main.c:(.text+0xde): referencia a `cfg_getstr' sin definir
main.c:(.text+0x104): referencia a `cfg_free' sin definir
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**UPDATE**:

I have tested [LibConfig](https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig) (as long as it is supposed to implement equivalent features) :

```
sudo apt-get install libconfig-dev
```

and, when trying to compile the included `/examples/example1.c` file, I get **equivalent results**: multiple undefined references on LibConfig functions.

Comment: 1. Code::Blocks is the IDE. The relevant language is C; the error would come up the same way if you used Atom or Sublime or Vim or any other editor; the only relevant difference is how you find the GCC command line (which would be useful to include in the question). 2. I would have expected the issue to be that you need to install `libconfuse-devel` or something similar; usually those are required. However, if that were the case I would expect it to have an error at the `#include <confuse.h>` line.

Comment: You were right, @DanielH : tested with `clang` compiler, and results are the same. Added info to original question.

Comment: What do you mean by "how you find the GCC command line?", @DanielH ? I just installed Code::Blocks with default compiling configuration. Added further data to reflect.

Comment: Code::Blocks doesn't have its own compiler. It shells out to `gcc` or `clang` (or maybe `make`, which in turn calls the compiler) when you tell it to compile your code. If you can find what the actual commands it's running are, that will help solve this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the linker where to find the libraries. 
Check https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=2159.

Comment: Indeed, referring `/usr/local/lib/libconfuse.a` at `Project --> Build Options --> Linker Settings --> Add` seems to solve the problem. Thanks you.

Comment: To note: on my tests, this solution compiles with static linking, so there is no need to install the `libconfuse` package on target system.

Comment: I would say that some more details would be proper from StackOverflow, Hubert. Links are not usually enough, as long as they could be deleted some day.